# Parse a string to different types

Tags: rust, type-systems

I have a list of sensor specifications. Each sensor type has an accompanying struct. A sensor spec has a sensor type and a key with which the data can be fetched from the database as a string.

Depending on the sensor type, the data should be converted into a numeric value, could be something like u8 or f64.

Here's an example:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

struct SensorSpec {
    sensor_type: SensorType,
    data_key: String,
}

enum SensorType {
    A,
    B,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SensorA {
    value: u8,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct SensorB {
    value: f64,
}

fn main() {

    // This simulates the database
    let mut db: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();
    db.insert("a".to_string(), "42".to_string());
    db.insert("b".to_string(), "13.37".to_string());

    // List of sensors
    let mut sensor_specs: Vec<SensorSpec> = vec![
        SensorSpec { sensor_type: SensorType::A, data_key: "a".to_string() },
        SensorSpec { sensor_type: SensorType::B, data_key: "b".to_string() },
    ];

    for sensor in sensor_specs {
        // 1. Fetch data as string from db
        // 2. Convert it according to the sensor type
        // 3. Print sensor object to terminal

        let val = db.get(&sensor.data_key);

        let s = match sensor.sensor_type {
            SensorType::A => {
                SensorA { value: val }
            },
            SensorType::B => {
                SensorB { value: val }
            },
        };

        println!("{:?}", s);
    }

}
```

There are two problems with this:

1. I need to convert the string to a numeric type depending on the sensor type. How do I do that?
2. Match arm have incompatible types.

Here's the compile message for #2:

```
example.rs:43:17: 50:10 error: match arms have incompatible types: 
expected `SensorA`,
    found `SensorB`
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please ask [only one question per question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/281829).

Comment: @Shepmaster the two questions are directly related. I do know how to convert types, but in the context of the two match arms it doesn't work. So no reason for a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

I'd replace your `SensorType` enum with the following one:

```
enum Sensor {
    A(SensorA),
    B(SensorB)
}
```

This has the advantage that you can put both classes of `Sensor` in the same container:

```
let sensorA = ...;
let sensorB = ...;
let mut vec = vec!( Sensor::A( sensorA ), Sensor::B( sensorB ) );
```

Or write your own functions that expect either class of `Sensor`:

```
fn use_sensor( sensor: &Sensor ) {
    match sensor {
        Sensor::A( sensorA ) => sensorA.foo(),
        Sensor::B( sensorB ) => sensorB.bar()
    }
}
```

Comment: @Shepmaster: Um, well, what do you want? A full rant about what algebraic data types are for?

Comment: No, but showing *how to use the enum* would be a good start. Your example doesn't show how the enum fixes the "match arm has incompatible types" error.

Comment: The question you need to think about, @Shepmaster, is "what is the type of s" in your code.  It can't be both SensorA and SensorB, but in Eduardo Leóns code, it can be Sensor.  Or in other words: The error message you get is not about the match itself, but about what should be returned from it, since the arms return different types.

Comment: @RasmusKaj thanks, but *I* understand how the enum would help ^_^. I'm more suggesting that the answer as currently provided doesn't provide the full amount of help that the OP might need.